# List all articles assigned to a Joomla! category

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

In the template overwrite for articles (`com_content/article/default.php`) I have to print all article titles which are assigned to a category idfentified by a specific id (which is statically embedded in my code).

*Here is a short example:*

I have the following categories:

```
Uncategorized (id = 0)
Mycat (id = 1)
 |- My subcat (id = 2)
Mycat2 (id = 3)
```

With this articles:

```
Travelling and the US -> MyCat
New York is a nice city -> My subcat
Give me some feedback -> MyCat2
...
```

And in my code I want now to list all the articles assigned to the category with id = 1. The output here should look like:

```
Travelling and the US
New York is a nice city
```

**UPDATE**:
For everyone who reads this and needs the same: the only way to do this is either to write a plain SQL query and run it through the Joomla! database API or to use such a plugin like ["list of articles"](http://www.joomlaboat.com/list-of-articles).

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you think that the change of php-code is needed here?

Answer (score 3):

This is what I'm using (inside a module that uses `loadPosition` to display on a content page)

```
//Use JModelLegacy to get all articles within $categoryID

$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Articles', 'ContentModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$appParams = JFactory::getApplication()->getParams();
$model->setState('params', $appParams);
$model->setState('filter.category_id', 'YOUR CATEGORY ID HERE'); //change that to your Category ID
$model->setState('list.ordering', 'title');
$model->setState('list.direction', 'ASC');

$articlesCategory =  (array) $model->getItems();

foreach ($articlesCategory as $artCat) {
  $artCat =  (array) $artCat;
  echo $artCat['title']  . "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: how can i get custom fields for each article with this query ?

Answer (score 1):

What would be better to use would be a Module on the page.
Extensions>Module Manager
New
Articles Category
Then in the options choose to filter to just "My subcat" not all categories 
Then assign that to the menu items to the pages that you want to show the list. either all pages or just one or two